# Laravel relationship with whereColumn condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Appears I'm trying to do something uncommonly complex or going about this the wrong way.  I can't seem to find anything online similar to what I am doing here.  I am trying to query a relationship where a column in the related table is equal to a column in the table of the model.

Given the following tables

```
| entity
============
id
...

| foo
============
id
entity_id
type_id
...

| baz
============
id
entity_id
type_id
...

| type
============
id
...
```

and Models

```
class Entity extends Model 
{
    public function baz()
    {
        $this->hasMany( Baz::class );
    }


    public function foo()
    {
        $this->hasMany( Foo::class );
    }
    //...
}


class Foo extends Model 
{

    public function entity()
    {
        $this->belongsTo( Entity::class );
    }

    public function type()
    {
        $this->belongsTo( Type::class );
    }
    
    //...
}


class Baz extends Model {
    
    public function entity()
    {
        $this->belongsTo( Entity::class );
    }


    public function type()
    {
        $this->belongsTo( Type::class );
    }
    
    //...
}


class Type extends Model 
{
    //...
}
```

I have the following code working, but in a different context Both Foo and Baz are filtered using $type_id

```
public function controllerActionWorking( Request $request, $type_id )
{

    // I'm using this in another place to get rows of Foo with type_id == $type_id.  Including Related Baz which also have type_id == $type_id
    $results = Foo::with( 
        [ 
            'entity.baz' => 
            function( $query ) use ($type )
            {
                return $query->where( 'type_id', $type->id ))
            }
        ])
        ->where( 'type_id', $type_id )
        ->get()
        
       // ....
}
```

**What I need is all Foo records, The Entity that goes with Foo, and Entities related Baz records where the Baz.type_id is equal to the type_id of the Foo record**.  this is non working code, but something like this is what I started trying first.

```
public function controllerActionHelpWanted( Request $request )
{

    $results = Foo::with( 
        [
            'entity.baz' =>
            function( $query )
            {
                
                // Here I need to verify the entity.baz.type_id = foo.type_id                
                
                // the following does NOT work
                // I get errros that 'foo'.'type_id' does not exist
                return $query->whereColumn( 'foo.type_id', 'baz.type_id' ) 
            })
        ])
        ->get()

    // .....

}
```

I can use a `join()` something like this

```
$results = Foo::with( 'entity' )
    ->join( 
        'baz',
        function($join)
        {
            return $join->on( 'foo.entity_id', 'baz.entity_id' )
                ->on( 'foo.type_id', 'baz.type_id' );
        })
    ->get()
```

That returns an instance of Foo with combined attributes of both tables.  It also looses the 'entity.baz' nested relationship.  which will matter in downstream code.

I could `$results->map()`  to filter the 'entity.baz' relationship after the query. I'd prefer to avoid the impact on performance if possible.

just seems like I'm missing something here.   Any help/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to read, when names are foo/baz and no logic reference is applied. Looks like many to many relation, where you can apply pivot.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
        ->withPivot('quantity', 'price'); // joins data from intermediate table
}
```

Pivot tables are queried by: $obj->pivot->quantity;

Comment: edited to better show relationships on Entity.  Entity has one to many on Foo and a one to Many on Baz.

Answer (score 0):

As far you wrap your question into faz/baz/entity it becomes quiet abstract to me, still :)

Let's try to make your query more model-side:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function entity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Entity::class, 'entity_id', 'id');
    }

    public function scopeTypes($query, $type_id)
    {
        return $query->where('type_id', $type_id);
    }

    public function scopeWithBazes($query, $type_id)
    {
        /* @var $query Builder */
        return $query->join('bazs', function($type_id) {
            return self::where('type_id', $type_id);
        });
    }
}
```

Inside controller I can do:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $foos = Foo::query()->withBazes(1)->get();

        foreach($foos as $foo)
            dd($foo->baz_name); // i placed baz_name in Baz table for test
    }
}
```

Well, drawback is that the table is joined. It is joined because you don't have any intermediate tables, so you need use joins etc.

Foo::types($type) will return collection of foos with type given.
Foo::bazTypes($type) will return joined table.

Still, these kind of problems appear when you omit intermediate tables, queries become more complex but database is a bit less robust.

If you were able to make that naming abstraction into 'real' problem, maybe people would play with it more. Just make foo => invoice, baz => address, etc, so perhaps you'll find better database schema for your scenario. Sometimes you will end up with multiple queries no matter what, but it's always worth asking :)

Comment: I'll have to test this, but the fact your passing an ID in to the scope tells me this may not be querying All Foo records and getting the Entities related Baz records that match the Foo's type_id